# Can I get only the new Facebook comments since the last time I checked instead of all comments every time?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-comments

Right now I have an app that allows a user to schedule/post a Facebook post and then monitor the likes/comments. One of the problems I foresee is that currently I am pulling every single comment/like whether it's been processed or not. What I would like to do instead is be able to say 'Give me all the NEW comments since XYZdate/XYZcomment.' Is this currently possible?

```
            var accessToken = existingUserNode.Attributes["accessToken"].Value;
            var facebookAPIMgr = new FacebookWrapper.FacebookAPIManager();
            var msg = new FacebookWrapper.FacebookMessage()
            {
                AccessToken = accessToken,
                FacebookMessageId = facebookPost.FacebookMessageId
            };

            //Get Facebook Message Comments
            // Need to find a way to limit this to only new comments/likes
            var comments = facebookAPIMgr.RetrieveComments(msg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do [time-based pagination](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/) as part of your graph API query.  If you keep a unix timestamp of when you polled things last, you can simply do `https://graph.facebook.com/{whatever}?since={last run}`.

This worked when I was working heavily with the Graph API earlier this year, and is still around on the documentation, but considering how much Facebook loves to change stuff without telling anyone you may still encounter problems.  So just a warning, YMMV.

Comment: I tried this with a FQL query and received: {Facebook.FacebookApiException: (NoIndexFunctionException - #604) Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql 
Will this get around that problem of time not being indexed?

Comment: @Justinwilliams Not sure, but the indexable column markings are wildly inaccurate on the dev site anyway, when I was working with them they were more often wrong than they were right.  This being the case, I would probably start with `/search?since={timestamp}` and start building a more complex query from there to narrow down what you want.  After you've got an idea of how it's working this week, you can refine it a bit more.  I'm sorry I can't be more help, usually when your knowledge is 6 months old it's fairly recent, but in Graph terms that's an eternity.

Comment: Using your comment as a starting place I was able to come up with my solution which was to use the 'offset' from paging. We were already keeping a count of the comments we had synchronized. If I've synchronized 5 since the previous query, I skip the first 5 and ask for anything after that.